# SQL Check Constraint on Table Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following check constraint to add to an existing table.

```
 ALTER TABLE  [dbo].[PROCESS_UPLOADDATA] 
ADD CONSTRAINT [PROCESS_RequireKeyFileOnMODE_Constraint] 
CHECK (
(RTRIM(LTRIM(LOWER(UPLOAD_MODE))) ='sftp' 
AND DATALENGTH(KEYFILE_PATH) > 2) 
)
```

The UPLOAD_MODE column is a column that does not allow NULLS and has values such as ftp or sftp. The KEYFILE_PATH column is an NVARCHAR(400) column with IS NULL default setting. However, in the case that the value in the UPLOAD_MODE is set to 'sftp', what I want is to make sure that a keyfile path is also provided.

**The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "PROCESS_RequireKeyFileOnMODE_Constraint". The conflict occurred in database "FILECONTROL", table "dbo.PROCESS_UPLOADDATA".**

When I execute however, I get the following error message. Would appreciate any help with this please. SQL SERVER database ! Thanks in advance.

```
//UPDATED SQL CHECK 


     ALTER TABLE  [dbo].[PROCESS_UPLOADDATA] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PROCESS_RequireKeyFileOnMODE_Constraint] 
    CHECK (
    CASE 
                     WHEN (RTRIM(LTRIM(LOWER(UPLOAD_MODE))) ='sftp' )
                        AND (DATALENGTH(KEYFILE_PATH) > 2) 
                       THEN 1 
                       WHEN   (RTRIM(LTRIM(LOWER(UPLOAD_MODE))) != 'sftp' )
                        AND (DATALENGTH(KEYFILE_PATH) < 2) 
                       THEN 1
                       WHEN   (RTRIM(LTRIM(LOWER(UPLOAD_MODE))) != 'sftp' )
                        AND ( KEYFILE_PATH IS NULL) 
                       THEN 1
                       ELSE   0

                       END =0
    )
```

After considering Andomar's suggestion/explaination, I was able to put together the above and wanted to be sure if the logic is correct for what I need here please. Again Thanks in advance.

Comment: What database is this?

Comment: are you sure the existing records comply with this new constraint?

Comment: all the current UPLOAD_MODE columns contain the value 'ftp', and the existing KEYFILE_PATH columns are mostly null or empty.

Comment: Run a query `SELECT * FROM dbo.PROCESS_UPLOADDATA WHERE NOT (your check constraint);` - if you get any rows back, you can see exactly why your constraint couldn't be created.

Comment: Well, there you go - as Andomar pointed out, this constraint dictates that every row has `'sftp'`... so it fails, because not every row has sftp...

Comment: I ran that with the updated and I get no rows back. Does than then mean it is correct?

Comment: If you only require that KEYFILE_PATH is populated when UPLOAD_MODE = 'sftp' then why not a much simpler constraint, like `CHECK ((upload_mode='sftp' AND datalength(keyfile_path)>2) OR (upload_mode <> 'sftp'))`? What you've got seem extraordinarily and unnecessarily complex.

Comment: (... like Andomar's update, sorry I hadn't noticed you simplified)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This check requires that all entries are `sftp`:

```
RTRIM(LTRIM(LOWER(UPLOAD_MODE))) ='sftp' AND DATALENGTH(KEYFILE_PATH) > 2
```

You probably mean:

```
RTRIM(LTRIM(LOWER(UPLOAD_MODE))) = 'sftp' AND DATALENGTH(KEYFILE_PATH) > 2
OR
RTRIM(LTRIM(LOWER(ISNULL(UPLOAD_MODE,''))) <> 'sftp'
```

That would allow `sftp` with a `keyfile_path`, and any other upload mode (including null) either with or without a `keyfile_path`.

Comment: I see what you mean. I was trying to add a check to make sure that if the UPLOAD_MODE Contains the value sftp, then the Keyfile_Path should not be empty. How to I instead add a constraint that requires that if the one is sftp, then the other cannot be empty or null?

Comment: +1 It could also be `CHECK (RTRIM(LTRIM(LOWER(UPLOAD_MODE))) <> 'sftp' OR DATALENGTH(KEYFILE_PATH) > 2)`